# Acumatica and Sales Order Screen - Create Shipment

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to find a way to modify the "Specify Shipment Parameters" dialog (that displays when you click the "CREATE SHIPMENTS" action).

I need to modify the default value for the Shipment Date. (based on a customer request).

[Sales Orders screen - CREATE SHIPMENT action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xmgex.png)

So far:

I have looked through Stack overflow and the Acumatica Community forum for suggestions

I have also looked through the Acumatica SOOrderEntry.cs source-code.

Starting on line: 523 (SOOrderEntry.cs)
Near the bottom of this code fragment, is the code: soparamfilter.**AskExt(true);**
I believe that line executes the "Specify Shipment Parameters" dialog.

public PXAction **createShipment;**
[PXButton(CommitChanges = true), PXUIField(DisplayName = OrderActions.DisplayNames.CreateShipment, MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, Visible = false)]
protected virtual IEnumerable CreateShipment(PXAdapter adapter,
[PXDate] DateTime? shipDate,
[PXInt] int? siteID,
[SOOperation.List] string operation)
{
List list = adapter.Get().ToList();

```
        if (shipDate != null)
            soparamfilter.Current.ShipDate = shipDate;
            
        if (siteID != null)
            soparamfilter.Current.SiteID = siteID;

        if (soparamfilter.Current.ShipDate == null)
            soparamfilter.Current.ShipDate = Accessinfo.BusinessDate;

        if (!adapter.MassProcess)
        {
            if (soparamfilter.Current.SiteID == null)
                soparamfilter.Current.SiteID = GetPreferedSiteID();
            if (adapter.ExternalCall)
                soparamfilter.**AskExt(true);**
        }
```

Thank you for any suggestion you may have. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer is to modify the default value.  Create the SOOrderEntry graph extension.  Then write the event handler for SOParamFilter defaulting method like this

```
public void SOParamFilter_SiteID_FieldDefaulting(PXCache sender, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
{
    e.NewValue = null;
}
```

Be aware a value is required.  The same applies for the date.

```
public void SOParamFilter_ShipDate_FieldDefaulting(PXCache sender, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
{
    e.NewValue = Base.Accessinfo.BusinessDate.Value.AddDays(30);
}
```

[image]